# Probability of riflemen shooting one after the other

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a shooting test between two riflemen. They try to shoot in the target in turns, and rifleman A shoots first.

The probability of shooting the target each time is (a/b) for rifleman A, while (c/d) for rifleman B.

The one who shoots in the target first is the winner.

Questions

- What is the probability that rifleman A will win the match?
- What is the probability that rifleman B will win the match?

Answer (score 1):

Let us define $p = \frac{a}{b}$, $q = \frac{c}{d}$, $P(A)$ as the probability of $A$ winning, and $P(B)$ as the probability of $B$ winning.

If $A$ shoot the target the first time he try - probability $p$, he win.

If $A$ miss the target the first time but $B$ miss too - probability $(1-p)(1-q)$, then it is $A$’s turn again and $A$ can win with probability $P(A)$. Therefore,

$P(A)=p+(1-p)(1-q)P(A)$

Solving for $P(A)$, we obtain

$P(A)=\frac{p}{p+q-pq}$

Probability of $B$ winning is simply $1-P(A)$

$P(B)=\frac{q-pq}{p+q-pq}$

Answer (score 0):

> > The answer for your question is the the summation of an infinite GP

Let 
a/b = $\alpha$
c/d = $\beta$
[For the sake of simplicity]

a. Probability A wins

Either A shoots the target in the first go **or** He misses the first time in which case B has to miss his shot and A shoots the second time **or** ...

Therefore,

P(A winning) = $\alpha$ + (1-$\alpha$)(1-$\beta$)$\alpha$ + (1-$\alpha$)(1-$\beta$)(1-$\alpha$)(1-$\beta$)$\alpha$ + .....

> > (1-$\beta$) because B has to miss his shot.

I hope you can try the second sub-question yourself, if you need help then feel free to ask.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: In your `P(A winning)`, you are missing a $(1-\beta)$ in the third term.

Comment: Thanks and edited it @AlainRemillard